# SQL Stored Procedure Variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i am testing this stored procedure thing and i tried using variables,

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @day int;
SET @day = 1;

IF (1 = 1) THEN

         SET @query = 'SELECT @day';

END IF;
               PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
               EXECUTE stmt;
               DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

this works perfectly fine with a different query and without declaring a variable,i know there is something wrong with the variables and i have researched a lot about this and i cant find any answers. i have this error

[image]

Comment: Please tag one DBMS, is this question about MySql or SQL-Server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL-Server, you must declare the variable: `@query`.

Answer (score 0):

Just got it.

I just need to do `SET @day := 1;` instead of `SET @day = 1;`